# How to make a moving svg shape disappear behind a static clipping path ?

Tags: svg, clip-path

Hi everyone I'm new to animating svgs and I would like to animate a shape so it disappears behind/in a static clipping path. I only managed to crop an object by using the clipping path but the path moves along with the object. How can I solve this by only using SMIL ? (In a later more precise Version I want the tube to disappear in the hole)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 


  <g transform="translate(750,105)">

 <ellipse cx="30" cy="162" rx="44" ry="28"
       style="stroke:#FEB102; 
       stroke-width:2; 
       fill:#F7CB1B"/>

  <defs>
    <clipPath id="cut-off-bottom">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="400" height="120" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <g clip-path="url(#cut-off-bottom)">

<path d="M0,15, L0,160 A18,10 0 0,0 60,160 L60,15"
    style="stroke:#BB3368; 
           stroke-width:2; 
           fill:#EE468E
          "/>

    <ellipse cx="30" cy="15" rx="30" ry="15"
       style="stroke:#BB3368;
              stroke-width:2; 
              fill:#EE468E"/>

   <animateMotion path="M0,120 L0,0 L0,120"       
          begin="0s" 
          dur="4s" 
          repeatCount="indefinite"
          /> 

    </g>

    </g>

 </svg>
```

Comment: Please fix your SVG so it works.  If people have to do work to get your SVG to display, you are much less likely to get an answer.

Comment: If you don't want the clipPath to move with the animated group, then don't put the clipPath on that group.  Wrap your animated group with a parent group and put the clipPath on that.